# .NET MVC Slow Site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, sql-server-2008, iis-7

I have a site that is taking around 20 seconds to load every page (no matter what it does)

So i put in a /scripts/test.html that isn't part of a route and it still takes this long... no db hit nothing.

I renamed the web.config to _web.config and it loads instantly, rename it back... back to around 20-30 second load times.

Running the application locally... i put a breakpoint on the RegisterRoutes in the Global.asax.cs and ran that... /scripts/test.html does not hit breakpoint normal site does (site loads instaly fast locally on the same database/code)

Server is Mosso IIS7/SQL Server 2008 Cluster

The site is being hit pretty hard... ANY help please? or things to test/debug?

Comment: Can you post your web.config file?

Comment: Any difference in speed depending on the browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few things to try:

- Try taking a look with FileMon/ProcessMonitor and see if there is a ton of disk activity.
- If the above is not an issue, install an instance of Dot Trace by Jet Brains. Profile the app and see if there is some memory or performance issue that is not apparent on your local box.

Comment: White Dragon, did you solve the problem, what was the solution? This answer points to a way to find the solution but not the solution itself, and I am very interrested in what you did find out to solve the problem...

Answer (score 0):

I saw another related issue that was solved by disabling IPv6, maybe try that.